# Postgres Index drop query performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

```
SELECT T.id_task,
        T.group,
        A.type
FROM TASK T
  JOIN ACTION A ON T.id_task = A.id_task

WHERE T.dt_inc BETWEEN 1511146800000 AND 1511492399999
  AND A.dt_scheduled BETWEEN 1511146800000 AND 1511492399999
  AND A.id_action > ( SELECT MIN(id_action) FROM ACTION WHERE T.id_task = id_task AND type <> 'TRANSFER' )
```

The original query is much bigger,  but the problematic part is here.

Its take one minute to finish, using only ( task.dt_inc, action.dt_scheduled ), BUT if i **DROP INDEX action_dt_scheduled**, the execution time drops to one second with same results using only ( task.dt_inc, action.id_task ) indexes.

- Why a index is performing so bad ?
- Can i ignore this index without droping it ?

I recreated the index DROP > CREATE, i make REINDEX wath should be the same than recreate, what can i do now ?

**EDIT:**

I was trying to get the EXPLAIN of the slow query, but this is not slow anymore, the ANALYSE and REINDEX of the tables has solved the problem.

Comment: definitions, description,statistics,explain analyze. BTW: the  `> ( SELECT MIN(id_action) FROM...` looks suspect (but: depending on the distribution of the data) These `1511146800000` numbers are actually timestamps?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I will get all the original stuff (tables, indexes, query) on the question, but i will need some time, can do right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more reasons why the performance can be worse with index instead without it:

1. bad estimations - when index is used, then random io is used. random io is usually significantly slower then seq scan - but if index selects small part of table, then it is acceptable. But when planner has bad estimation of result, then index can be used although the seq scan is better. You can check the estimation by `EXPLAIN ANALYZE query` command.
2. bloated index - a state of index can be bad if long time index was not reindexed - then access and usage of index can be slow.
3. wrong sized `effective_cache_size` parameter - when this paremeter is not accurate or it is not safe, then pages of index can push from RAM a heap (table) pages. In this case a page cache (*shared buffers*) is not stable - you can check the stability of shared buffers with a `pg_buffercache` extension. Too low `shared_buffers` can have similar effect.

Comment: I have Postgres 9.2 - Linux - 32 GB Ram ( Server only for Postgres and OS ) with effective_cache_size = 21GB, not sure how to analyze this in this version of Postgres.
I executed vacuum analyze in the action table and configured the auto vacuum - analyze, it was not aggressive enough, lets see how will be in the rush hour, tank you.

Comment: have you original values for `seq_page_cost` and `random_page_cost`? Can you paste via https://explain.depesz.com/ result of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` command. What is value of `share_buffers`. Personally I am thinking so `effective_cache_size` 21GB is too much.

Comment: I will get all the original stuff (table, query) on the question, but i will need some time, can do right now

Comment: The ANALYSE and REINDEX of the tables has solved the problem